# How to require confirmation for git reset --hard?

Tags: git, bash

How to I make sure that git asks for confirmation on any hard reset?

I have had this several times. The terminal bugged out(bash history navigation) and showed me only the last part of the command... I pressed enter and to my surprise reset all my changes.

So is there a way to make sure that under normal operation git asks for a confirmation when performing a hard reset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git itself doesn't implement this (for good!), and it's impossible to alias a built-in Git command, so I see two ways:

- A custom wrapper — something like

  ```
   # cat >/usr/local/bin/mygit
   #!/bin/sh
   set -e -u
   if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
       if [ "x$1" = "xreset" -a "x$2" = "x--hard" ]; then
           echo 'Sure?'
           read resp || exit $?
           test "x$resp" = "xyes" || exit 0
       fi
   fi
   git "$@"
   ^D
   # chmod +x $_
   $ mygit reset --hard
  ```
- Shell aliases:

  ```
  cat >>~/.bashrc
  alias git /usr/local/bin/mygit
  ^D
  ```

  Where `/usr/local/bin/mygit` is taken from the previous point.

**Update** to incorporate the suggestion of William Pursell — a shell functon which "overrides" the external command:

```
# cat >>~/.bashrc
git() {
    set -e -u
    if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
        if [ "x$1" = "xreset" -a "x$2" = "x--hard" ]; then
            echo 'Sure?'
            read resp || return $?
            test "x$resp" = "xyes" || return 0
        fi
    fi
    command git "$@"
}
^D
```

After that, plain `git blah ...` in a shell would call the wrapper function while direct `/usr/bin/git` would call Git directly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, good catch, but better yet to drop the word `function` -- it's [a bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).

Comment: Impressive: the word `function` was edited out at most 5 seconds after I'd posted it.  Good to see more people complaining about bashisms!

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yeah ;-) Not that it was really relevant (the OP explicitly told he's using `bash`) but I consider this to be a good practice anyway. And by the way, I'm afraid [`command` is not in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html). Added another example as per your suggestion.

Comment: Sure it is:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed.
 
I disagree that it's "for good", most operations that cause loss of data in Unix'es require an explicit flag be it -q or -f. Hard reset on Git is just another function, that's concealed as a switch.

Comment: @JAlexoid, I mildly disagree: 1) Think of `git reset --hard` as of `rm -f`: `--hard` just enables a potentionally destructive mode; 2) A similar effect might be achieved by a combination of `git checkout` on paths and `git clean` -- should we also make any of these require a special switch `--yes-please-go-destructive`? 3) (Boring) real-life experience (I see how regular GUI users work) suggests no amount of nagging with questions is able to save a user from losing their work -- they promptly learn to "click-through" them.

Comment: @JAlexoid, I recall RedHat aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` in their stock setups: you just learn to hit `y`, `Return` when it asks you whether you really wish to delete the files.

Comment: @kostix However git reset --hard is not the day-to-day operation. Hard reset is not a thing that I use often(does anyone use it often?), so adding a default interactive mode to it would draw my attention that it's not the usual process. As described, I would have caught that maven rarely asks for user input. So yes, nagging often does not work, but nagging at the right time is absolutely the right thing to do.

Comment: Putting `set -e -u` in a function that's going to be called in an interactive shell is a **very** bad idea -- that change to the shell's state applies not just to the function but to everything else after it's been called. And `set -e` [isn't a particularly good practice in the first place](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). (Even if you skip the allegory, *do* see how many of the questions after it you're able to answer correctly).

Comment: (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304602/how-to-prevent-git-from-quitting-when-i-use-tab-completion as a follow-on question caused as a consequence of the use of `set -e -u` here).