# Command Line alert me for a command

Tags: git, terminal

I'm using git. I work on several branches. However, sometimes, in mishap, I pull from master. I try immediately to revert back to the state before pull (This I'm aware of). However, this doesn't remove some extra added files in the project. So I wish terminal could alert me before for particular set of commands. How is this possible?

I use `GitX` for maintaining the commits. It shows that these files are still in my un staged changes, even though I ask to discard all changes. Hence the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a shell script to wrap some of the *dangerous* git commands and let the script ask for confirmation. You can see an example of wrapping the `git reset --hard` command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180467/how-to-require-confirmation-for-git-reset-hard). You can easily adapt that script to your needs.

Another solution is to have some `git` status info on your prompt. In this way you can see in which `branch` your working or if you have a dirty index and so on.
For the bash shell you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt/15883676#15883676)