# How to prevent git from quitting when I use TAB completion?

Tags: git, bash

I want git to require confirmation for resetting, so I updated  [William Pursell's suggestion written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180467/how-to-require-confirmation-for-git-reset-hard#_=_) like this:

```
git() {
set -e -u
if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
    if [ "x$1" = "xreset" -a "x$2" = "x--hard" ]; then
        echo "Are you sure? (Type 'yes')"
        read resp || return $?
        if [ "x$resp" = "xyes" ]; then
            echo "Resetting"
        else                
            echo "NOT Resetting"
            return 0
        fi
    fi
fi
command git "$@" || :
}
```

With this it won't quit from the console if I mistype the command, but it still quits if I try to use TAB completion. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `set -e -u` is a bad idea in general. **Especially** inappropriate here, but in other cases as well. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112) -- and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Comment: BTW, `[ "$resp" = "yes" ]` is perfectly correct. There's absolutely no need for the antiquated `x$resp` idiom -- it fixes ambiguities that only exist in uses of `test` that are deprecated by the [modern POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (with `-a` and `-o` combining multiple distinct tests in a single invocation; note the "[OB]" next to these in the standards document marking the syntax obsolescent), and you're not anywhere close to any of those corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `set -e -u`. Those settings are global to your shell session, not local to your function, and they conflict with the shell completion functions which are not immune to undefined variables (`set -u`). And since your function is well written, you need neither `set -e` nor `set -u`.